# loss function design to incorporate different weight for false positive and false negative

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I am trying to solve a semantic segmentation problem. In accordance with the real constraints, the criteria for false positive and the criteria for false negative is different. For instance, if a pixel is miscorrected as foreground is less desirable than a pixel is miscorrected as background. How to handle this kind of constraint in setting up the loss function.

Comment: Currently, I am just using binary_corrsentropy as the loss function, and I am curious to see whether it is possible to add weight for different class labels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `class_weight` parameter of [`model.fit`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) to weight your classes and, as such, punish misclassifications differently depending on the class.

> `class_weight`: optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) to apply to the model's loss for the samples from this class during training. This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

For example:

```
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')
model = Model(input=..., output=out)
model.fit(X, Y, class_weight={0: 1, 1: 0.5})
```

This would punish the second class less than the first.

Comment: Is there a way to do that element wise? Could I simply weight the output of a binary_cross entropy accordingly? What if true positives should be weighted differently than true negatives as well (and not just the positives as in your answer)?

Comment: In the end you can multiply any term you please with the output of your loss function but in order to do this you need to write your own loss function (i.e. supply a function that takes `y_pred` and `y_true`, compute your loss and multiply your weight vector).

Comment: But wouldn’t a binary cross entropy function always produce a loss between 0 and 1 (0.5 meaning that y_true==y_pred). Wouldn’t scaling that distort the loss function?

Comment: Can anyone gives more math behind how does class_weight works ?

Comment: @AmanDalmia basically: `weights[class[i]] * loss(y_true[i], y_pred[i])` where `class` is a mapping of sample index to respective class. and `weights` is a mapping of class to weight. therefore, the loss is re-weighted according to the class of the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jaccard distance (or IOU) loss function in keras-contrib:

> This loss is useful when you have unbalanced numbers of pixels within an image
>       because it gives all classes equal weight. However, it is not the defacto
>       standard for image segmentation.
>       For example, assume you are trying to predict if each pixel is cat, dog, or background.
>       You have 80% background pixels, 10% dog, and 10% cat. If the model predicts 100% background
>       should it be be 80% right (as with categorical cross entropy) or 30% (with this loss)?

Source:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/blob/master/keras_contrib/losses/jaccard.py